# WP8 Maps control - Get name of the City with await function

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, maps, async-await

I have a function to get the city name:

```
private async Task<string> OnMapHold()
{
    ReverseGeocodeQuery query;
    List<MapLocation> mapLocations;
    MapLocation mapLocation;

    query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    query.GeoCoordinate = MyCoordinate;

    mapLocations = (List<MapLocation>)await query.GetMapLocationsAsync();
    mapLocation = mapLocations.FirstOrDefault();

    if (mapLocation != null)
    {
        return mapLocation.Information.Address.City;
    }
    return "No City";
}
```

And in my main function I call this function like:

```
    string town = await OnMapHold(); // Error?
```

But here comes the error: In System.InvalidOperationException is an exception of type "mscorlib.ni.dll" occurred. But I don't know what to do. I think my await and async is wrong, but how do I do it right?

EDIT:

I worked now with this [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrspinella/archive/2012/11/02/using-reversegeocodequery-for-windows-phone-8.aspx) example and it works for me.

Comment: GetMapLocationsAsync is not part of ReverseGeocodeQuery, can you add information for this [extension] method

Comment: Ok, I worked with this example: [Using ReverseGeocodeQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrspinella/archive/2012/11/02/using-reversegeocodequery-for-windows-phone-8.aspx) , and now it works for me.